# TypeScript check string match type

Tags: typescript

I have something like this:

```
type UnionType = 'one' | 'two' | 'three'

const myNumber: string = 'just a string'

// function to check if myNumber match UnitionType
```

Is there any way to do that? because I don't want to write:

```
['one', 'two', 'three'].includes(myNumber)
```

Comment: You will either have that value at compile time and then you can just do `const myNumber: UnionType = 'just a string'` which won't compile, or you don't, and then you have to do `['one', 'two', 'three'].includes(myNumber)`

Comment: "I don't want to write: `['one', 'two', 'three'].includes(myNumber)`" Can you articulate why you don't want to do this?  At runtime there is no `UnionType` so there's no way to inspect it with JavaScript.  If you want to be DRY you can express the type in terms of the array, but not vice versa.  See [this code](https://tsplay.dev/mbdg3w) for a possible approach.  Does that work for you?  If not, please edit the question to explain how it fails to satisfy your use cases.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change `type` into an `enum`,
then you can easily make an comparison with your string with the keyword `in`.

```
enum UnionEnum {
    'one',
    'two',
    'three'
}

const myNumber: string = 'just a string';

// function to check if myNumber match UnitionType

console.log(myNumber in UnionEnum); // Result -> false
```